# Androild Studio Emulator Not Launching: Intel Haxm Not Installed

Tags: android

I was trying Android Studio - successfully installed it but couldn't launch the emulator and the error message was Intel Haxm wasn't installed. I checked my setting and realized it was installed.

1. I tried to re-run it several times and the same thing happened.
2. I tried to install SDK 17 and the error was still there.

May I know what might be causing this? And how should we solve it?

Thank you.

Comment: when you create a new avd can you try selecting arm instead of intel runtime?

Answer (score 0):

You was created an AVD with Intel Atom system image, so make sure that your CPU is Intel. If yes, see this [instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows) about installing HAXM on your computer.
If HAXM won't to be installed, please make sure that your CPU is strong enough to use HAXM. Then, change the system image of your AVD to ARM-v7 or Armeabi.

System image also called with CPU type of the emulator on AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to run Android Apps on computer:

If you are not able to use Android Studio Emulator (at all after trying above given solutions), then you can use [**Genymotion**](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/). It comes with free as well as paid versions. You can download this software on your Windows/Mac/Linux based computer and configure it with Android Studio/Eclipse.

Watch this video for more details: [Install and configure Genymotion with Android Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twMx545ZoSs)

Genymotion is fast and reliable and also has latest (till Lollipop 5.0) android support and provides many emulator themes as well.

I hope this answer helps you if above mentioned solution doesn't work.